# Python 3: "NameError: name 'function' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Running

```
def foo(bar: function):
    bar()

foo(lambda: print("Greetings from lambda."))
```

with Python 3.6.2 yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

However, removing the type annotation works as expected.

PyCharm additionally gives the warning `'function' object is not callable` on line `bar()`.

---

**edit:** As stated in my comment of Pieters’ answer, this question raised, because

```
def myfunction():
    pass

print(myfunction.__class__)
```

outputs `<class 'function'>`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no name `function` defined in Python, no. Annotations are still Python expressions and must reference valid names.

You can instead use type hinting to say `bar` is a *callable*; use [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable):

```
from typing import Any, Callable

def foo(bar: Callable[[], Any]):
    bar()
```

This defines a callable type that takes no arguments and whose return value can be anything (we don't care).

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting it to be valid, because checking a functions class, via `print(myfunction.__class__)` yields `<class 'function'>`.

Comment: @qwertz: sure, but that  doesn't mean that there is a global name `function` referencing the type.

Answer (score 3):

### Absolute Answer

```py
from types import FunctionType as function

def foo(bar: function):
    bar()

foo(lambda: print("Greetings from lambda."))

print('-' * 30)
print(function)
print('type(foo) is function:', type(foo) is function)
print('type(foo) == function:', type(foo) == function)
print('function is foo.__class__:', function is foo.__class__)
print('function == foo.__class__:', function == foo.__class__)
print('callable(foo):', callable(foo))
```

Execution result:
[image]